# Use Flickr as my screensaver

Tags: mac, screensaver, flickr

I'd like to have a Screensaver on my Mac using Flickr pictures.
How do I do it? Any suggestions for a simple way? Can I Make some kind of selection of the pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately (due to some dumb actions by Apple), this is no longer a simple process to do. Until 10.8 this was a ridiculously simple undertaking, but now it's quite an annoyance.

remember this URL--> you'll need it later:  https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne

You'll need to follow these steps to download software, then you can configure it to feed the flickr url into your Mac.

http://mac-how-to.wonderhowto.com/how-to/get-apples-rss-visualizer-back-as-screensaver-mac-os-x-10-8-higher-0156457/

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in El Capitan.  :c

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, a time ago I found this new app that allows to make a screensaver with flickr photos, web pages and so; in a very easy way. It's called [Screensaver Ninja] (1), I recommend to try it.

(1) https://screensaver.ninja/knowledge-base/flickr-slideshow/